# Unable to call adapter procedure in MobileFirst V8.0 Consumer Edition

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I am using MobileFirst V8.0 Consumer Edition. I have setup a test server for my app. When I am calling the adapter procedure(which is protected by the security check) from the mobile app I am getting below error in the server:

```
[8/25/16 15:10:08:879 CDT] 0000010b com.ibm.mfp.server.az.internal.ConfidentialClientHelper      E Unable to sign access token
com.ibm.mfp.server.security.shared.webtoken.WebTokenException: com.ibm.mfp.server.security.shared.webtoken.WebTokenException: Unsupported credentials type
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.security.shared.webtoken.JWS.sign(JWS.java:191)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.az.internal.ConfidentialClientHelper.generateAccessToken(ConfidentialClientHelper.java:94)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.az.internal.token.TokenEndpointImpl.generateTokenResponse(TokenEndpointImpl.java:170)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.az.internal.token.TokenEndpointImpl.serveAuthorizationCodeGrantType(TokenEndpointImpl.java:147)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.az.internal.token.TokenEndpointImpl.getToken(TokenEndpointImpl.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:473)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:912)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.ibm.mfp.server.security.shared.webtoken.WebTokenException: Unsupported credentials type
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.security.shared.webtoken.PKICredentials.getRsaPublicKey(PKICredentials.java:120)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.security.shared.webtoken.PKICredentials.createWebKey(PKICredentials.java:96)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.security.shared.webtoken.PKICredentials.createHeader(PKICredentials.java:48)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.security.shared.webtoken.JWS.sign(JWS.java:186)
    ... 32 more
```

Also, I am using User Defined keystore in my MFP server Instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Regenerated the keystore using below command with `-keyalg RSA` option as described in [this](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_mfp_server_keystore_configuring.html) documentation and reconfigured the keystore and this error went away:

```
keytool -keystore <keystore name> -genkey -alias <alias name> -keylag RSA
```

Earlier I refered the  guide  in MFP Console named Create Your Own keystore in the MobileFirst Console from following location `Runtime Settings --> Keystore` and there `-keyalg RSA` option was missing.

[image]